# Can i increase the cost of my paid android app in Google play store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Can i increase the price of my paid android app in Google play store?

Just Assume.
Today, I published my app at the cost of $1. Can i increase the cost of that app will $5 in future?

If you say "yes, you Can Increase", how many times can i change the cost of my paid app in google play store?

Comment: You can increase / decrease it whenever you want.

Comment: try cost++ or cost+=5 ... oh wait ... it is not about programming

Comment: Is stackoverflow only for programs? @Selvin

Comment: *Is stackoverflow only for programs?* no, about programming, read the FAQ!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can change it as you please using the android developer console.

1. Select an app
2. On the left menu, click Pricing & Distribution

The only thing you must remember is that if you change it from paid to free, the change is permanent. There is no way to reverse this change without uploading it as a brand new application